# У документа удален файл кода

Tags: wpf, xaml

Удалил у MainWindow.xaml файл code-behind и затем создал заново. При добавлении в разметке событий на элементы VS говорит:

> "У элемента документа отсутствует файл кода программной части. Перед
>   добавлением обработчиков событий добавьте файл кода программной части
>   и определение класса."

Как восстановить связь между файлом кода и разметки?
[image: Structure]

Comment: У вас разные названия, в одном случае `MainWindow`, а во втором `MainWindows`, должно быть без "s"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это можно сделать при помощи ручной правки .csproj-файла. Но проще всего — просто скопируйте текст .xaml- и .xaml.cs-файлов, удалите их, добавьте через Visual Studio новое окно, и замените сгенерированный текст на сохранённый.

---

Если и правда хочется покопаться в .csproj, элемент, описывающий зависимый .xaml.cs-файл должен выглядеть так:

```
<Compile Include="MainWindow.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>MainWindow.xaml</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>Code</SubType>
</Compile>
```

Обратите внимание на часть `DependentUpon`.

И не забудьте выгрузить Visual Studio на время правки проекта.

Answer (score 1):

`x:Class="ВашеНазваниеПроекта.MainWindow`
и

```
namespace ВашеНазваниеПроекта    {
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


}
```